# How can I make a form with multiple entities under symfony 5?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have been blocked on my project for a long time trying to figure out how to do a multi-entity form in symfony 5. I looked at a big number of people having a problem like mine but I couldn't find any satisfying answers.

To sum up, I want to list plants that are stored in my database as ['vegetals'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5s1c.png)

There are, in other tables, the fruits and leaves of that plant that I'd like to add in my database with a form at the same time. But what I have done so far are 3 separate forms, which isn't good for UX. Do you have any idea of what I should do ?

Here are my vegetal Controller :

```
     * @Route("/Vegetal/ajouterVegetal", name="ajouterVegetal")
     */
    public function ajouterVegetal(Request $request)
    {

        $vegetal = new Vegetal();


        $formVegetal = $this->createForm(VegetalType::class, $vegetal);
        $formVegetal->handleRequest($request);

        
        if ($formVegetal->isSubmitted() && $formVegetal->isValid()) {

            $vegetal = $formVegetal->getData();

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($vegetal);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        } else {
            return $this->render('Vegetal/ajouterVegetal.html.twig', array('formVegetal'  => $formVegetal->createView(),));
        }
   }
```

my vegetalType :

```
class VegetalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class)

            ->add('nomFrancais', TextType::class)

            ->add('origine', TextType::class)

            ->add('hauteur', TextType::class)

            ->add('floraison', TextType::class)

            ->add('sol', TextType::class)

            ->add('exposition', TextType::class)

            ->add('utilisation', TextType::class)

            ->add('interets', TextType::class)


            ->add('enregistrer', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Vegetal',
        ));
    }
}
```

my ajouterVegetal (to add one) :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">   
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4 form-ajout">
                {{ form_row(formFeuille.petiole,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }} 

                {{ form_row(formFeuille.persistance,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }}

                {{ form_row(formFeuille.forme,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }}

                {{ form_row(formFeuille.margeFoliaire,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }}

                {{ form_row(formFruit.couleur,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }}



{{ form_rest(formFeuille) }}
```

There is only just vegetal, because the other ones are pretty much exactly the same, that's why i didn't put them here. Tell me if I have to give you some more info !

Comment: _There are, in other tables, the fruits and leaves of that plant that I'd like to add in my database with a form at the same time._ Can you specify that differently, maybe give an example workflow of what fields you want and what output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create/edit two related entities in the same form with their parent.

You have to prepare Forms for FruitType and LeafType, then you have to add them to the parent form in this way:

```
class VegetalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class)
            ->add('nomFrancais', TextType::class)
            ->add('origine', TextType::class)
            ->add('hauteur', TextType::class)
            ->add('floraison', TextType::class)
            ->add('sol', TextType::class)
            ->add('exposition', TextType::class)
            ->add('utilisation', TextType::class)
            ->add('interets', TextType::class)

            ->add('fruit', FruitType::class)
            ->add('leaf', LeafType::class)

            ->add('enregistrer', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Vegetal',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that, but it gives me the message "Class "App\Form\Leaf" not found. Is the "data_class" form option set correctly?". To try and correct this, I have put 'App\Form\Leaf' behind it, but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: @KevSIO I can recommend using maker bundle to generate new form Types: `php bin/cosnole make:form`. Make sure you have setted up correctly in child forms:
```
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Leaf',
        ));
    }
```